# Set of values of a complex number when a given expression involving the number is given to be real

Tags: complex-numbers

If $w = \alpha + i\beta$, $\beta \ne 0$ and $z \ne 1$ satisfies the condition that $\frac{w-wz}{1-z}$ is purely real, then set of values of $z$ is 
$$(a) |z| = 1, z \ne 2 $$ 
$$(b) |z| = 1, z \ne 1 $$ 
$$(c) z = \overline{z} $$ 
$$(d) None $$

My attempt: I assumed $ z = x + iy$.
Substituting this in the given expression and assuming that the expression reduces to a purely real value implies that the imaginary part must be zero.
Hence we reach to a simplified equation $$(x^2 - 2x + 1 + y^2) = 0  $$
$$=> (x-1)^2 + y^2 = 0$$

The right option is provided as (b).
I can't conclude to the right option from here. Could you please help me to solve the question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to have four options (a)?

Comment: @MathsLearner Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

HINT: For $z\neq1$ your expression is equal to $w$, so not real.

And if you are still unsure, the answer is (a). The last (a). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If $z\neq1$, we have $\frac{w-wz}{1-z}=\frac{w(1-z)}{1-z}=w=\alpha+\beta i$.
That is never purely real if $\beta\neq0$.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{w(1-z)}{1-z}=w$$ if $z\ne 1$

Comment: You mean if $z\ne 1$?

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i meant! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is real

$$\frac{w-wz}{1-z}=w\frac{1-z}{1-z}=w$$

and $$w=\bar w$$

is not possible since $\beta \ne 0$.